# Is there a way to capture audio and video in dart, in a single data flow?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, video, streaming

I want develop an video call application for mobile. I search a lot but I dont' find a library in flutter, dart programming language for capture audio and video from webcam and microphone. I want get a single data flow/stream thus I can send it via socket from client to client.

Can you tell me if there is a way to capture video with audio and send it via socket with dart?

Comment: try this package ```https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine```

Comment: thank you, I have find this https://pub.dev/packages/camera
Does this capture also audio?

Comment: @zabitsack yes you can

Comment: very good news!